# Transaccion con paypal en nodejs

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, servidor, paypal

Tengo una duda, lo que quiero hacer en un servidor que tengo con nodejs es que al momento de que un usuario realice un pago con paypal, un porcentaje de ese dinero vaya a otra cuenta. 
Por ejemplo, un usuario compra un articulo a 3 dolares, y en ese mismo momento de esos 3 dolares, hacer el pago correspondiente al proveedor y otro porcentaje que me quede ami, en pocas palabras es como hacer una transaccion de mi cuenta a otra pero que todo sea manejado desde el servidor y que el cliente o usuario no vea nada de eso.

Answer (score 0):

En primer lugar tendrías que llegar a un acuerdo con tu proveedor.

No se puede hacer directamente tendrías que hacer dos transacciones a diferentes cuentas de PayPal lo mejor que puedes hacer es transferir todo a tu cuenta y desde allí transferir el dinero a el proveedor, en el desglose puede añadir un campo que diga cargo por servicio. de esa forma puedes mantener un control de que cantidad de dinero te corresponde a ti y tu proveedor.

Como en este ejemplo de un sitio web que administro. 
[image: sitio web paypa]